# how to get data from static dropdown list to model in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one static dropdown list in my view

```
<select>
 <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 <option value="saab">Saab</option>
 <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
 <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to bind this drop down list with my model so that when I submit selected value of drop down , I get that value from model in my controller.

Also I want to select option in drop down as per data in my model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just made list item for static dropdown list & passed it to dropdown list where I binded it with my viewmodel.

```
 @{
   var listItems = new List<ListItem> {new ListItem {Text = "Single", Value = "Single"}, new ListItem {Text = "Married", Value = "Married"}, new ListItem {Text = "Divorse", Value = "Divorse"}};
   }
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EmployeeDetail.MaritalStatus, new SelectList(listItems),"-- Select Status --")
```

It works perfectly for me as it shows value which comes from model & also stores value of dropdown list in model when I submit data.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of constructing the drop down list in HTML, build it in your service/controller and add it to your model:

ViewModel:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCarManufacturer { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> CarManufaturers { get; set; }

    // your other model properties
}
```

Controller get action method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var model = new YourViewModel
    {
        SelectedCarManufacturer = null, // you could get this value from your repository if you need an initial value
        CarManufaturers = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "volvo", "Volvo" },
            { "saab", "Saab" },
            { "audi", "Audi" },
            /// etc.
        }
    };

    return this.View(model);
}
```

In your view, replace the hard coded drop down list with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCarManufacturer , new SelectList(Model.CarManufaturers , "Key", "Value"), "Select a manufacturer...")
```

Controller post action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeSaveAction(YourViewModel model)
{
    // do something with the model...
    // model.SelectedCarManufacturer 
}
```

OR

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeSaveAction()
{
    var model = someService.BuildYourViewModel()
    this.TryUpdateModel(model);

    // do something with the model...
    someService.SaveYourViewModel(model);
}
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: I have to make dropdown list in view only. Also I have one value in my model which has to be selected value of my dropdown list.

Comment: Why, may I ask, does the dropdown list need to be made in the view only?

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Volvo", Value = "volvo"});

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Saab", Value = "saab" });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Mercedes", Value = "mercedes" });

     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Audi", Value = "audi" });
```

on view

```
Html.DropDownListFor(Model.items)
```

Comment: I have to make static dropdown list in view only. Also I have some value in my model which have to be selected value in this dropdown list.